# Command to find N Largest files in macOS directory excluding specific directories

Tags: bash, macos

I want to find the largest files in my project, but excluding `.target` folder.
so far I have found the following command, but not sure how to exclude `.target` folder.

`find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -hr | head -n 10`

Also please share what will be the command, for excluding multiple directories.

Comment: please let me know why my question is downvoted.

Comment: I just had a look at recent Apple source code, and Apple `sort` does now have `-h` and `--human-numeric`. I was looking at an out of date man page.

Comment: Not my downvote, but please search for duplicates before asking.

Comment: the linked question didn't solved the problem,

Comment: @SahibYar Can you please explain why the linked question does not solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `-path` and `-prune` to exclude the `.target` directory:

```
find . -path ./.target -prune -o -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -hr | head -n 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
find . -type d -name .target -prune -o -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -hr | head -n 10
```

- `-prune` is an action to skip the matched directory in the previous
  condition.

If you want to exclude multiple directories, you can
append the directory name, say "exclude2", with `-o` such as:

```
find . -type d \( -name .target -o -name exclude2 \) -prune -o -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -hr | head -n 10
```

Comment: `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have known macOS `find` does not support `-printf` option. I've fixed my code adapting your original `-exec` command.

Comment: seems like, `prune` not working, I can still see ./target files in the search.